# 2 SharePoint farms with 2 different domains

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have a SharePoint farm that is configured with domain A. We have another farm located in another server configured with domain B. We have a requirement to transfer the second farm into the server that is configured with domain A. Is it possible? Can someone outline high-level steps involved in this migration?

Thanks in advance
Inv

Answer (score 0):

To move SharePoint farm from one domain to another, Here are the high level steps.

- Create a new Farm in the new domain A.
- Create the web applications, Service Applications and apply the customization
- Now move the content db from old farm (from domain B) to new for sql server( domain A).
- Now run the migrate user so that all users moved from Domain b to Domain a
- Update the AAM, DNS record to point new server.